# How to copy data from one file to another with Windows batch script?

Tags: batch-file

I am a little familiar with shell scripts but not so much with Windows batch scripts. Need some help converting this shell script to a batch script. Also how is current directory (.) like in the example below (./src/test/...) written in a batch script?

In the example below, I check to see if test.xml exists. If it does not exist, I copy data from abc.xml to test.xml.

```js
if [[ ! -f test.xml ]] ; then
    echo 'File "test.xml " is not there. Copying dummy file.'
    cp ./src/test/abc.xml test.xml
fi
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for examples of file existence in Windows Batch programming? How about copying a file? What have you tried and where have you encountered any problems?

Comment: Hi Anthony, yes I did look for some examples, but I got a little lost trying to copy using xcopy and setting the source and destination directories relative to where Bamboo was generating results. Ken's solution worked great.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `if not exist` and `copy`. You specify the current directory the same way, using the backslash instead of the forward slash as directory separator, or just start your reference there without using a backslash at all.

```
if not exist test.xml copy .\src\test\abc.xml .\test.xml
```

or

```
if not exist test.xml copy src\test\abc.xml .\test.xml
```